# Логирование внутри докер контейнера

Tags: laravel, docker

Есть приложение на docker контейнерах. Приложение написано на Lumen(Laravel) и ведет логи внутри себя по дням. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы в конце каждого дня файл лога архивировался. Как можно это реализовать? Внутри Dockerfile установить расширение для логирование и как-то его настроить? Или же лучше написать свой микросервис, который будет срабатывать с помощью крона, но в такой случае при разворачивании на сервере будут лишние шаги?

Comment: правильно будет отправлять логи не в файл, а в stdout/stderr. и [средствами docker-а проводить ротацию](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/).

Comment: Логи не должны храниться в контейнере. Вы можете в любой момент пересоздать контейнер и потеряете логи. Выносите их на volume. И дальше настраивайте стандартное средство вашей ОС на архивирование. Но как сказал выше @aleksandr barakin самым правильным будет вывод логов приложением в stdout